# PHP tool for creating, populating and displaying html tables

Tags: php, html-table

I have a question about creating HTML tables using PHP. I love the way that some libraries handle the SQL create, read, update and delete (CRUD) by using PHP components that can do CRUD without the need to know any SQL but with PHP API's instead.

I need a tool with which I can create HTML tables the same way. I want to create HTML or other ML tables only using PHP statements.

Can anyone suggest a good tool to use for creating HTML tables with PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to create html tables with php ?

Comment: Well, one suggestion would be that I can prepare one table attributes, styles etc and then inject results sets into it and this will populate the table. The other is that I can (probably) have implementation in the old html and html5 automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed such tools for developing HTML forms using PHP.

My first choice as a PHP developer is the PEAR's `HTML_Table`. As the documentation says "[PEAR's] HTML_Table makes the design of HTML tables easy, flexible, reusable and efficient."

Using this component is a easy as including the table class (from a file), instantiating a new instance, add a body and start appending rows to the table all using PHP calls.

Here is an example of a table that shows users' name, email and age.

This example assumes that you already have `PEAR` installed ([Install PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.php)) as well as PEAR's [HTML_Table](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.html-table.php).

The first thing to do is to include the PEAR's `HTML_Table`

```
<?php require_once 'path/to/pear/HTML/Table.php'; ?>
```

You might also need to include the `HTML_Common` & `PEAR` classes as well so it is good suggestion to have the PEAR path in your PHP `include_path`.

To deal with this and in general with PEAR class loading, have a look at [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) standard which is the PEAR naming conventions of classes and files. This might be useful when working with autoloaders.

Having the class(es) available we can create a table like this:

```
// Instantiating the table. The first argument is the HTML Attributes of the table element
$table = new HTML_Table(array('class' => 'my-table'), null, true);
```

Note that all parameters are optional.
Lets first add header to the table:

```
// Preparing the header array this will go in <table><thead><tr>[HERE..]</tr></thead></table>
$headerRow = array('Name', 'Email', 'Age');
$header = $table->getHeader();
$header->setAttributes(array('class' => 'header-row')); // sets HTML Attributes of the <thead /> element
$header->addRow($headerRow, null ,'th');
```

So far the HTML of this table looks like this:

```
<table class="my-table">
    <thead class="header-row">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Lets add a body and some rows:

```
// This is array of arrays that will represent the content added to the table as table rows (probably retrieved from DB)
$resultSet = array(
    array(
        'name'  => 'John Doe',
        'email' => 'john.doe@example.com',
        'age'   => 33,
    ),
    array(
        'name'  => 'Jane Doe',
        'email' => 'j.doe@example.com',
        'age'   => 30,

    ),
);

// $bodyId is the body identifier used when appending rows to this particular body
$bodyId = $table->addBody(array('class' => 'main-body'));
foreach ($resultSet as $entry) {
    $indexResult = array_values($entry); // <-- the array passed to the addRow must be indexed
    $table->addRow($indexResult, array (/* attributes */), 'td', true, $bodyId);
    // note how we specify the body ID to which we append rows -----------^
    // This is useful when working with multiple table bodies (<tbody />).
}
```

The concept of multiple `<tbody />` tags within a table can also be taken advantage of with the `addBody()` method of the table class which returns body identifier to be used as reference when appending rows later on (see coments above).

Having that, displaying the table is as easy as:

```
<?php
    echo $table->toHtml();
    // or simply
    echo $table;
?>
```

The HTML content of this example now looks like this:

```
<table class="my-table">
    <thead class="header-row">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="main-body">
        <tr>
            <td>John Doe</td>
            <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
            <td>33</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jane Doe</td>
            <td>j.doe@example.com</td>
            <td>30</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps :)

Stoyan.